# Why is my table empty after CSV import to PostgreSQL(pgAdmin)?

Tags: sql, postgresql, csv

I have created a table and would like to import the data in my csv file over to pgAdmin. The following were the queries executed in the query editor :

```
create table offline_trx
(sale_key varchar(50),
order_id varchar(50),
country_code varchar(10),
qty_ordered integer,
qty_refunded integer,
extended_gmv_sgd DECIMAL(19,9),
extended_net_amount_sgd float DECIMAL(19,9),
product_sku varchar(50),
product_type varchar(20),
category varchar(20),
created_at_time_ist date
);
```

...and the below query to copy data from csv file ...

```
COPY public.offline_trx(
    sale_key, order_id, country_code, qty_ordered, qty_refunded, extended_gmv_sgd, extended_net_amount_sgd, product_sku, product_type, category, created_at_time_ist)
FROM 'C:\Users\Sam\Downloads\offline_trx.csv'
DELIMITER ','
CSV HEADER;
```

After executing the above copy query, it showed that the query returned successfully. But when I select the table appears to be empty. So I'm not sure what am I missing. Is there a way that I can inspect the logs somewhere to better understand what exactly happened that resulted in it appearing to be "missing"?

Comment: `extended_net_amount_sgd float DECIMAL(19,9),` <<-- syntax error

Comment: @wildplasser I've changed it to integer it still doesn't work, the datatype of the column is a float, a decimal number up to 9 places after the period, I don't understand how this syntax is wrong, could u be more specific how is that wrong ?